# loop to pass bulk values into python api request

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, loops

I have an API built in Python that outputs data and takes in the input parameter 'ID', and outputs a set of fields. The parameter does not allow bulk values to be passed and to work around this, I have tried to create a loop to make one call per Id. Below is an example of what I tried:

```
    ID = '19727795,19485344'
#15341668,
fields = 'userID, agentID, internalID'
 
#add all necessary headers
header_param = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken,'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*'}

for x in ID:
    response = requests.get(Baseuri + '/services/v17.0/agents/' + x + '?fields=' + fields , headers = header_param)
```

Even this loop returns an error '404 Invalid ID'

What is the way to pass a list of args into the ID parameter? I have to run this code at least once a day and need a way to pass multiple values in.

Comment: Well right now `ID` is a string, and iterating over a string just returns the individual characters.

Either do `ID = ['first_id', 'second_id', ...]` or do `for x in ID.split(',')`

Comment: @Lagerbaer using ID = ['first_id', 'second_id'] doesn't work since it is showing 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str. Using for x in ID.split(',') is only pulling back the last ID that was passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not allow bulk IDS and it is your API, you have two choices that I see. You either A) allow it server-side, or B) do this:

```
fields = 'userID, agentID, internalID'
field_list = fields.split(",")

for field in field_list:
    pass
```

Really, it just boils down to if you want your client-side code to be more simple or your server-side to be more simple because it is more or less the same process regardless of the end it is on. On the other hand, f-strings are more efficient and cleaner (subjective) to use:

```
response = requests.get(Baseuri + '/services/v17.0/agents/' + x + '?fields=' + fields , headers = header_param)
```

will turn into:

```
response = requests.get(f'{BASE_URI}/services/v17.0/agents/{x}?fields={fields}', headers = header_param)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be the ID field that needs to be split? What is the purpose of splitting the fields list?

Comment: what is the difference really. All you need to do is change the values accordingly, and both of the strings have the exact same format.

Comment: the point is that you use the .split() string method

Comment: The above works, with one adjustment - the dict. output from the response has to be appended into a single dict since the for loop overwrites the previous value